# How do we can use both the headless mode option and user-data-dir option?

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, headless

I want to use both of the two options for screenshot sites need login.

- headless mode `--headless`
- specify user data directory `--user-data-dir` (set fullpath on Windows)

But this seems not to work correctly because headless driver does not hold login status.
(in the below code, I used function construct_driver and the argument headless_flg=True)

I created the user-data (and profile dir) that is read from the headless driver by creating and opening the user-data firstly from the normal driver (no headless option, login the sites, and persisted.

I confirmed that the normal driver correctly read the same profile and already logined the site from second driver run.
(in the below code, I used function construct_driver and the argument headless_flg=False)

So, I think the cause of this problem is that headless driver do not read the user-data correctly.
Is there the way to specify the user-data on headless chrome driver?

This is my code (python):

```py
from selenium import webdriver as wd
from selenium.webdriver.chrome import service as cs

BASE_DIR = "<fullpath of the user data dir to be located>"
DRIVER_VERSION = "101.0.4951.41"
def construct_driver(headless_flg=False, profile_no=1):
    csi = cs.Service(f"{BASE_DIR}/{DRIVER_VERSION}/chromedriver")

    options = wd.ChromeOptions()
    userdata_dir = f"{BASE_DIR}/data/Chrome-{str(profile_no)}"
    if(headless_flg):
        options.add_argument('--headless')
    options.add_argument(f"--user-data-dir={userdata_dir}")
    # profile = "1"
    # options.add_argument(f"--profile-directory=Default")

    driver = wd.Chrome(service=csi, options=options)
    driver.implicitly_wait(10)
    return driver
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with phyton, but managed your request in C#.

There are two complete different options and the start sequence.

Maybe it will help you a little bit or give you an idea.

```html
// hide driver Console? true/false 
ChromeDriverService service = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
service.HideCommandPromptWindow = false;

// change Standard-Download-Folder
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
var downloadDirectory = GlobalVars.RootPath + GlobalVars.strSymbol;
options.AddUserProfilePreference("download.default_directory", downloadDirectory);
options.AddUserProfilePreference("download.prompt_for_download", false);
options.AddUserProfilePreference("disable-popup-blocking", "true");

// start Selenium Driver:
webdriver = new ChromeDriver(service, options);
```